# Error '80040e07' when trying to add a record in Access database

Tags: ms-access, asp-classic

I am getting error 80040e07 when trying to add a record in Access using classic ASP. The code was working perfectly yesterday.

> Microsoft JET Database Engine error '80040e07'
>
> Data type mismatch in criteria expression.
>
> /alumni/admin/addvalue.asp, line 3

The fields *btitle*, *bname*, *baddress*, *bphone* and *bpincode* can be blank while others are mandatory.

My code:

```vbs
dim conn, rs, t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7, t8, t9, t10, t11, t12, t13, t14, t15, t16, t17, t18, t19, t20, t21, concat, sqlstr
Set conn=Server.createObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs=Server.createObject("ADODB.Recordset")
conn.open="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source="&Server.MapPath("\alumni/alumni.mdb") & ""
t1=Request.form("txtfname")
t2=Request.form("txtlname")
t3=Request.form("txtprn")
t4=Request.form("txtbdate")
t5=Request.form("gender")
t6=Request.form("txtmail")
t7=Request.form("txtaddrs")
t8=Request.form("txtcity")
t9=Request.form("txtstate")
t10=Request.form("txtpincode")
t11=Request.form("txtpphone")
t12=Request.form("txtsecphone")
t13=Request.form("drpdegree")
t14=Request.form("drppassyear")
t15=Request.form("txtdesg")
t16=Request.form("txtcname")
t17=Request.form("txtcaddr")
t18=Request.form("txtccity")
t19=Request.form("txtcstate")
t20=Request.form("txtcpincode")
t21=Request.form("txtcphone")
t22=Request.form("txtcmail")
concat=t14&t3
if(t20="")then
    t20=0
end if
sqlstr="insert into users(userid,passwd,utype,ufname,ulname,uprnumber,ubdate,ugender,uemail,uaddress,ucity,ustate,upincode,upphone,usphone,udegree,upassyear,btitle,bname,baddress,bcity,bstate,bpincode,bphone,bemail)values('"&t6&"','"&concat&"','student','"&t1&"','"&t2&"','"&t3&"','"&t4&"','"&t5&"','"&t6&"','"&t7&"','"&t8&"','"&t9&"','"&t10&"','"&t11&"','"&t12&"','"&t13&"','"&t14&"','"&t15&"','"&t16&"','"&t17&"','"&t18&"','"&t19&"','"&t20&"','"&t21&"','"&t22&"')"
response.write("this is the string"&sqlstr)
'response.write("THIS IS PASSWORD "+concat)
rs.open "insert into users(userid,passwd,utype,ufname,ulname,uprnumber,ubdate,ugender,uemail,uaddress,ucity,ustate,upincode,upphone,usphone,udegree,upassyear,btitle,bname,baddress,bcity,bstate,bpincode,bphone,bemail)values('"&t6&"','"&concat&"','student','"&t1&"','"&t2&"','"&t3&"','"&t4&"','"&t5&"','"&t6&"','"&t7&"','"&t8&"','"&t9&"','"&t10&"','"&t11&"','"&t12&"','"&t13&"','"&t14&"','"&t15&"','"&t16&"','"&t17&"','"&t18&"','"&t19&"',"&t20&",'"&t21&"','"&t22&"')",conn
```

JavaScript code:

```js
var fname = '<%=t1&t2%>';
var email='<%=t6%>';
var passwd='<%=concat%>';
alert('hi,'+fname+'your regestration is successful.'+'\nyour Id='+email+'\nPassword='+passwd);
window.location="http://localhost/alumni/default.asp";
```

Comment: Be careful about your numeric fields. There is no need to use single quotation(' ') when you are inserting into database. On the other hand must use single quotation while inserting a string. Insert a valid data that matches to datatype

Comment: If it's resolved now following @polin comment please let him know (use `@` to notify like I did now) then he'll post this as answer that you can accept.

Answer (score 2):

Disable the `rs.open` line like this ...

```
'rs.open "insert into users ...
```

Then open `addvalue.asp` in your browser and copy the output from this line.

```
response.write("this is the string" & sqlstr)
```

Start up Access, create a new query, switch to SQL View, and paste in what you copied as the output from `sqlstr`.  If viewing the SQL statement doesn't immediately clarify the data type mismatch error, you will have to inspect the data type of each field in the fields list and compare that with the value you're attempting to insert.

However, in your ASP code, I think you should use an ADO Command object with your `INSERT` statement revised as a parameter query.  Then add the values with the [Parameters Collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675869%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing to an Access file using classic ASP your code above looks to be written in php. You don't Insert into ASP, you update or Add new. Since there are multiple ways to make a connection I wont get into the connection string but your query syntax should

Example:

```
 rs.open "users", conn, 3, 3
 rs.AddNew

 rs("passwd")=request.form("password")
 rs("username")=request.form("username")
 etc...

 rs.update
 rs.close
 conn.close
```

Comment: This is totally valid classic ASP code, it was badly formatted that's all. +1 for the suggestion,the `AddNew` can indeed make things more simple sometimes.